# Watch Objects / Strings other than this.state

Tags: react-native, watch

In **ReactNative**, is there a way to watch for changes to `strings` or `objects` other than the `this.state` object?

I have heard about `Object.watch`, but this seems like a deprecated desktop solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check ES6 proxies:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy

Example:

```js
const setHandler = {
  set(obj, prop, value) {
    console.log('Updating property ' + prop + ' to ' + value);
    obj[prop] = value;
    return true;
  }
};


const unmonitoredObject = {a: 0};
const monitoredObject = new Proxy(unmonitoredObject, setHandler);
monitoredObject.a = 1;

//Output: Updating property a to 1
```